# Why is PayPal not working inside a WinRT WebView control

Tags: windows, webview, paypal, windows-runtime

I am writing a Windows 8 app where the user is able to do in-app purchases. Our Client provides us with a REST API. Basically I get product information from this REST API and if the user chooses to buy a product I tell the REST API to start a transaction.

As a result I am receiving a PayPal URL for the payment transaction. I am navigating to that URL using the `WebView` control that is built into the WinRT. Unfortunately the PayPal website does not behave properly in the `WebView` control. When I am signing into PayPal, the purchase overview page where I am able to pay for the product is loaded, but after one or two seconds the `WebView` reloads and I am on the sign-in page again.

At first I thought there was a problem that is specific to my app, so I started a new vanilla project, which just hosts a `WebView` control that navigates to the PayPal URL (there is no other interaction or anything). But still I got the same result.

If I try the PayPal URL in other browsers (e.g. Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer 10 or Metro Style Internet Explorer) everything works fine and I could not reproduce the error. So I guess there is something wrong with the `WebView` control.

Now I am wondering if anyone else had the same problem and if you could give me some pointers on how to solve this problem?

Comment: I would be surprised if Paypal allowed any wrapper that could eavesdrop on a transaction.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by eavesdropping? That I am able to inject JavaScript into the site? Well, I am able to do that with any major browser

Comment: Interesting. Can you tweak the URL to be in the form   https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout-mobile&token=<token> and see if it works?

Comment: Even if I tweak the URL to be in the form paypal.com/cgi-bin/… I get the same result: I log on and after one or two seconds I get logged off again.

Comment: @stark you could do this easily with fiddler or any debugging proxy though (or man in the middle attack or or or or) but I could definitely see the point of 'wanting' to do that, although in practice it could be intercepted without much difficulty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted a PayPal evangelist and we figured out that the problem might be that the `WebView` is sending it's own user agent string. PayPal refuses to work with the `WebView` because the programmer might inject JavaScript into it (e.g. for invoking the pay button or eavesdrop on customer data). So I guess @stark was right. As I have already told @Adam Tuliper, we removed PayPal from our list of supported payment providers.

Answer (score 1):

There's this open source project meant for integrating with PayPal for WinRT
http://paypal.github.io/Windows8SDK/

Comment: I found that project, too, but unfortunately it would require my customer to rewrite the REST API and us to implement the whole PayPal transaction. Since our Project is due in a few days, that is not feasable for us. Therefore we removed PayPal as a payment provider.