# Windows UWP Launcher.LaunchUriAsync method to open a browser popup dialog

Tags: windows, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I have an application in Windows UWP(for desktop/tablet and phone) and I am integrating with Paypal payment gateway. When I am ready to pass the data to paypal, i need to open a popup browser and show the paypal dialog for users confirmation.(page https://checkout.paypal.com/one-touch-login-sandbox/index.html)

I am trying to open the page using Launcher.LaunchUriAsync as shown below,

```cs
Uri uri = new Uri(args.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
LauncherOptions options = new LauncherOptions();
options.TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName = "Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe";

LaunchUriResult result = await Launcher.LaunchUriForResultsAsync(uri, options);
```

This code is opening the Microsoft Edge browser but it is not showing the popup message rather I get the callback in NavigationCompleted method with IsSuccess as true. Also, immediately after the callback, browser disappears which is preventing me to confirm the payment to proceed with transaction.

Also, I get the message as "Don't see secure paypal browser? We'll help you relaunch the windows to complete your purchase" with a continue button but the continue button is not responding in UWP application. When I get the same message in my website, continue button shows the popup browser in the front for the user to respond.

I would like to know if there is a better way to open a browser from UWP application and get a confirmation once the browser transaction is successful?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The code to open the browser is not working even when I try with http://www.google.com. `Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
LauncherOptions options = new LauncherOptions();
options.TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName = "Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe";

LaunchUriResult result = await Launcher.LaunchUriForResultsAsync(uri, options);`

Answer (score 1):

I think you went into a wrong direction integrating with Paypal payment gateway in your UWP app. There is security problems, it's not possible to use your method to integrate Paypal, here is a case on SO you may take a look [Why is PayPal not working inside a WinRT WebView control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244427/why-is-paypal-not-working-inside-a-winrt-webview-control).

After a little bit research, I found that there is no official SDK for integrating Paypal in an UWP app for now, and even there is one, it should be intended for use by trusted clients (e.g. servers the merchant controls) and is not intended for use by untrusted clients (e.g. anything that runs on a machine that isn't controlled by the merchant).

It is now recommended to open a web browser from your app to complete the transaction via [Braintree v.zero](https://www.braintreepayments.com/payment-methods/accept-paypal), you can also check the official [Paypal Developer Experience](https://developer.paypal.com/).

Comment: I am trying to do the same with the code snipped I mentioned above. Now I am running the code without a WebView rather I am trying to open Edge browser directly from UWP app with paypal checkout URL. I get  result.Status as LaunchUriStatus.Success but result.Result is null. It is trying to open the browser and it disappears immediately.

Comment: @NidheeshPuthalath, but you are using `LaunchUriForResultsAsync`, this request the target app to handle your quest, and send info back to source app when finish the work. I doubt Edge would do this work for you.

Comment: I realize that and tried await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri, options); method as well. This also behave the same way as the other method.(ie. opening the Edge browser and closes immediately). Like I mentioned in the above comment, I have tried this with http://www.google.com as well and the result is same.Does this means that opening a browser with a url should be handled differently in UWP?

Comment: @NidheeshPuthalath, No, I think only the navigation to the link like paypal you provided should behavior like this, as I mentioned, it should be security problems. Navigate to normal link like google shouldn't actor like this,  and use ` Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri, options);` to open a link, it opens the default app for browser, it is set by user, not always Edge. I just tested, you set `options.TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName = "Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe";`,  remove this option, it will launch successfully. I'm curious how did you confirm this is Edge's package family name.

Comment: Thank you @Grace. I have removed the family name and it took the default browser in UWP desktop app. But when I tried the same in WP emulator,it had the same issue of popup not showing with message "Don't see secure paypal browser? We'll help you relaunch the windows to complete your purchase" with a continue button.Continue button is showing the popup in desktop browser(Chrome in my case) and not responding in WP browser. Do you think if this is related to the Paypal security issue you are talking in the about post?

Comment: @NidheeshPuthalath, Looks like so, and by WP you mean windows 10 mobile? In a word I'm saying basic on the investigation I did, you will need to follow the Paypal's official develop document to integrate it.